# .each() function returns only one value, other undefined

Tags: jquery

I have button, which make append new input to the `<fieldset>`.  I try to know all values from from this input. So I use for this `.each()`.

See example of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var addNewPhone = $('#addNewPhone');
    var sendPhone = $('#sendPhone');
    var phoneFieldset = $('#phones');
    var save = [];

    var addPhone = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputcode = '<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phones" value/>';
        phoneFieldset.append(inputcode);
    }

    var savePhone = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var phonetemp = $('#phones').children().filter(':input');
        phonetemp.each(function(index){
            console.log($(this).eq(index).val())
        });

    }

    addNewPhone.on('click', addPhone);
    sendPhone.on('click', savePhone);

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PhhG6/

So in console I can see value of first input, but other are undefined.

Can somebody help me? What I didn't wrong?

Comment: My code http://jsfiddle.net/PhhG6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.eq` was breaking it - no need to check the index when running thru the each loop:

```
phonetemp.each(function(index){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/PhhG6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use:

```
console.log($(this).val())
```

instead of:

```
console.log($(this).eq(index).val())
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhhG6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access directly by index do the following:

```
console.log(phonetemp.eq(index).val());
```